# Show/hide of Form + Toggle link text; ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass) - thinks model instance is nil?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to toggle link text upon showing and hiding a form, but when I run the server I get a 500 internal server error. I'm trying to add a "solution" to an "aspect", and render the solution form with Jquery, toggling it when the link text changes from 'add solution' to 'cancel'.

Here is `show.html.erb` for an aspect:

```
<p>
  <h1><%= @aspect.title %></h1>
  <%= @aspect.brief %>
</p>

  <% if @solutions.count > 0 %>
    <h4>Solutions:</h4>
    <p>Number of solutions: <%= @solutions.count %></p>
      <ul class="media-list solutions">
      <% vote_order(@solutions).each do |solution| %>
            <%= render solution || "No solutions found" %>
    <% end %>
  </ul><!-- .solutions -->
<% else %>
    <p class="no solutions">
     This aspect does not yet have a solution. Why don't you describe one?
    </p>
    <ul class="media-list solutions">
  </ul><!-- .solutions -->
<% end %>

<p class="solutions">
  <%= link_to "Add solution", new_aspect_solution_path(aspect_id: @aspect.id, idea_id:  @idea.id), remote:true %>
</p>
```

And `new.js.erb` for solution:

```
var selector = "ul.solutions"
if($("p.cancel").length == 0){ 
    $(selector).append("<li class='js-inline-form'><%= j render :partial => 'solutions/form' %></li>")
    $("p.solutions").replaceWith("<p class='cancel'><%= j link_to 'Add solution', new_aspect_solution_path(aspect_id: @aspect.id, idea_id: @idea.id), remote:true %></p>")
}
else if($("p.solutions").length == 0){
    $(selector + " li.js-inline-form").remove()
    $("p.cancel").replaceWith("<p class='answers'><%= j link_to 'Add solution', new_aspect_solution_path(aspect_id: @aspect.id, idea_id: @idea.id), remote:true %></p>")
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
    1: var selector = "ul.solutions"
    2: if($("p.cancel").length == 0){ 
    3:  $(selector).append("<li class='js-inline-form'><%= j render :partial =>   'solutions/form' %></li>")
    4:  $("p.solutions").replaceWith("<p class='cancel'><%= j link_to 'Add solution', new_aspect_solution_path(aspect_id: @solution.aspect.id, idea_id: @solution.idea.id),   remote:true %></p>")
    5: }
    6: else if($("p.solutions").length == 0){
    7:  $(selector + " li.js-inline-form").remove()
  app/views/solutions/new.js.erb:4:in `    _app_views_solutions_new_js_erb___206213221362185261_2207575120'
  app/controllers/solutions_controller.rb:15:in `new'
```

Don't really understand why it doesn't know what an id is when all I'm doing is creating a new

tag with the exact same content, calling the exact same action. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update:**

Also added

```
def set_aspect_idea
  @aspect = Aspect.find(params[:id])
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
end
```

method to the `solutions_controller`, and set it before the `:new` action. I ran everything again and got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Aspect without an ID):
  app/controllers/solutions_controller.rb:90:in `set_aspect_idea'
```

I don't really understand what's going on.

**Update 2**

I changed `new.js.erb` to this:

```
var selector = "ul.solutions"
if ($(selector + ".js-inline-form").length == 0) {
    $(".js-inline-form").remove()
    $(selector)
        .append("<li class='js-inline-form'><%= j render :partial => 'solutions/form' %></li>")
}
else {
    $(".js-inline-form").remove()
}
```

And removed the `set_aspect_idea` from the controller and it works, but there is no toggling of the link text.

If I keep `set_aspect_idea` before the `new` action, I get thrown the same error as in `update 1` above.

The problem is clearly in the `replaceWith()` part of the original `new.js.erb` file; even though the form is loaded onto an @aspect page, it thinks the @aspect is nil. Why is this?

Comment: make sure `@solution` is not nil ..

Comment: But this is just a form for submitting a solution? @soluton != nil only if the form is actually submitted, not when its toggled?